# PHP echo end($array) not printing anything

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to echo the last value of my array. For some reason it's not printing anything. I can echo  a specific value for example

```php
echo $array[0]['weight']
```

prints the first value.

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM calorycalc2 WHERE userid = $id[0]";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

echo end($array['weight']);
```

Comment: Is `$array['weight']` an array itself?

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: BTW `$array['weight']` will always be the last value as it's out of the loop

Comment: Try `print_r($array)` if for debugging

Comment: try `var_dump($array)` and tell us what it says

Comment: You want end($array)['weight'], not end($array['weight']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the last element of the outer array `$array`, *then* access the sub-index `weight`.

Notice how the brackets are changed in place. `end($array)` fetches the last element, and that itself is an array, which you can access the element with `['weight']`

```php
echo end($array)['weight'];
```

By doing  `echo end($array['weight']);`  as you were originally doing, you are asking PHP to fetch the last element of the array which is `$array['weight']`, but there is no such index `weight` (there is only numeric indexes, `$array[$x]`) in `$array`.

Comment: That said, if you only intend to use the last element, you might as well just fetch that directly from MySQL. No need to fetch everything, loop it and only use the last element. :-)

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem. I'm new in coding so rookie mistakes are inevitable :D

Comment: Also keep in mind when you need to access other elements: end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.end.php) `end` returns the last entry in an array, so what I can guess from you code is that you want this:

```
echo end($array)['weight'];
```

What you are doing is accessing the entry with the key `'weight'` `$array['weight']` (that's a number I guess) and passing that value to the `end` function. Since the `end` function expects an array and not a number this will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last element of the array in this way

```
echo $array[count($array)-1]['weight'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 row of result on your query. Because you are accessing a row of result with a specified id. In this case you don't need to loop the query. It require only if you have multiple row of results.
To access the last element

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM calorycalc2 WHERE userid = $id[0]";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

$array = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)
$i = 0;
while($row as $key=>$value) {
   $array[$i] = $value;
   $i++;
}

echo end($array);
```